# Gamma function identity proof

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, special-functions, alternative-proof, gamma-function

When trying to prove: $\Gamma\left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right)=\dfrac{2^{1-n}\sqrt{\pi }(n-1)!}{\left ( \frac{n-1}{2} \right )!}$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, by mathematical induction, I cannot get a relation between $\Gamma \left ( \frac{n}{2} \right )$ and $\Gamma \left ( \frac{n+1}{2} \right )$ to make the proof valid. Is there anything I'm missing or maybe another way to prove it?

Comment: One potential idea: perhaps you could do induction on firstly odd $n$ and then for even $n$ and verify the above formula?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Done and verified for both cases individually. Thanks a lot for the clue.

Comment: No problem at all!